# Msg 33299, Level 16 when using Always Encrypted Column in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, always-encrypted

I have a table named Product which has a field named Code varchar(50).

I used `Always Encrypted` on this field. `Insert` and normal `select` is working fine.

But when I am trying create a stored procedure to `select` with `WHERE` clause on `Code` field it is showing an error and not allowing me to create the procedure. My procedure code is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductByCode]
@productCode VARCHAR (50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  id,
        [Name],
        Code,
        Price
    FROM   Product
    WHERE Code = @productCode;
END
```

The error it is showing is as follows:

> Msg 33299, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetProductByCode, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@productCode', 'Code'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto2', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'xxxx') and the expression near line '11' expects it to be (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC') (or weaker).

Why it is not allowing me to create the procedure?

I tried by setting Column Encryption Setting=Enabled in the Connection.

Enable Parameterization For Always Encryption is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [document](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-69-always-encrypted-limitations/)

> Columns using randomized encryption are not supported in clauses at
>   all

The column `code` in this case is having **Randomised encryption**.
This encryption type should only be used for columns that are just for display, not for querying.

So if you want to query using the column `code` change its encryption type to **Deterministic**.

Columns using deterministic encryption support `WHERE` equality comparisons, as well as `DISTINCT`, `JOIN`, and `GROUP BY`.

You cannot perform inequality, range, or LIKE queries, or any other operations against encrypted columns.

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) too.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/